# printf for negative float numbers using %d

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to use the `printf` function to give out the value of a float variable for that I can only use `%d`, here is what I've done so far:

```
.............................
float var =0.0;
// the value will set from another function 
var *= 100000;
printf("X[%d.%04d] \n",(int)(var / 100000),((int)var)%100000));
...............
```

this works fine with positive float value , but when I get negative ones this how  it'll be displayed :

for : `-0.4578   -> 0.-4578`
as you can say the sign isn't in right place , my question is if there is a way to do this without using for example : `switch case` statemente or something similar ? 
thanks in advance !

Comment: `value *= 100000;`....did you mean `var *= 100000;`

Comment: @Sourav yes sorry about that !

Comment: float literals are written (using the values in the posted code) 0.0f  and 10000.0f ,    a literal with no decimal point is neither float nor double.  a literal with a decimal point and no trailing 'f' is a double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using different format strings for positive and negative numbers:

```
char *format;
int v = var * 100000;
if (v < 0) {
    format = "X[-%d.%04d] \n";
    v = -v;
} else {
    format = "X[%d.%04d] \n";
}
printf(format, v/100000, v%100000);
```

This way `v` is always positive in `printf`, and the sign is embedded into the format string that you pass. Only `%d` format is used.

Comment: @dasblinklight, thanks for your answer, but 1 problem I can only use %d, so no %s ,%f %c etc.

Comment: Surely you meant `10000` in 3 places rather than `100000`.

Comment: @chux Right, either that, or `%05` in place of `%04`. I'm sure OP will figure out this part.